# Does it code like conditional operation in php?

Tags: jquery

```
var src = $(this_image).attr('src') || '' ;
```

Does the above code look like conditional operation in php ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means if `$(this_image).attr('src')` is undefined. `src` will be equal to `''`

Comment: In addition, if you wanted a boolean response... `var src = typeof $(this_image).attr('src') !== "undefined"`

Comment: Its more than that. If `src` is `undefined`, `var src` would be equal to `''`

Answer (score 2):

An expression of the form `expr1 || expr2` in Javascript is equivalent to the PHP conditional expression `expr1 ? expr1 : expr2`.

You can't use the simpler expression in PHP because its && and || operators always return booleans.